# Linker error for StrRetToBuf function

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mfc, windows-shell

So I have this error:
       Error    1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_StrRetToBufW@16 referenced in function _wmain

I include:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <shlobj.h>
 #include <shlwapi.h>
 #include <iostream>
```

and I call the function like this:

```
 StrRetToBuf(&strDispName, pidlItems, pszDisplayName, MAX_PATH);
```

So there is a linker error. Any fixes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference page for [`StrRetToBuf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) states that you must link with `Shlwapi.lib`.

Answer (score 1):

You should link your project with `Shlwapi.lib`. It is the import library for the DLL where `StrRetToBuf` resides in.